# count number of times selectbox values

Tags: php

for a quiz i use this form:

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
<p><strong>HOOFDSTAD VAN PERU?</strong><br> 
<select name="v1"> 
<option value="0">Kies een antwoord</option> 
<option value="1">SANTIAGO</option> 
<option value="2">PERU-STAD</option> 
<option value="3">MANAGUA</option> 
<option value="4">LIMA</option> 
</select> 
<hr> 
<p><strong>Hoofdplaats van Provincie Luxemburg?</strong><br> 
<select name="v2"> 
<option value="0">Kies een antwoord</option> 
<option value="1">EUPEN</option> 
<option value="2">ARLON</option> 
<option value="3">GIVET</option> 
<option value="4">MARCINELLE</option> 
</select> 
<hr>
and so on...
```

i use this code for the right value

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') 
{


if($_POST['v1'] == '4') {
$v1 = 1;   
}
else {
    $v1 = 0;
}

if($_POST['v2'] == '2') {
$v2 = 1;   
}
else {
    $v2 = 0;
}

// and so on...

    // count the number of times that $v1 till $v5 == 1 and echo the number


}
```

**Question 1:** How can i count the number of times that the values are equal to 1?
Because the output should be something like: 7 of your answered questions are correct

**Question 2:** lets say i have 100 questions in the quiz; can it be done more efficient than the way i do it at the moment? with the if/else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ar = (...)//array of correct answers
$counter = 0;
for($i=0; $i<$noLines; $i++){
   if($_POST['v'.$i] == $ar[$i]) 
       $counter  += 1; 
}

echo $counter." of your answered questions are correct";
```

Comment: I'm glad i helped! you may want click the big V to accept it as the answer :)